# AsyncTask call in sleepmode

Tags: android, android-asynctask

**PROBLEM**

I have problem with `MigrateAsyncTask` not calling my adapter about finished job while being in sleep mode.
How to fix such problem?

Everything is working fine while device is awake.

**CONSTRUCTION**

- `DashboardFragment` that is holding my grid of items and `adapter` that is suppose to get called.
- `DialogFragment` is responsible for showing info and also is implementing `MigrateAware` interface.
- `MigrateAsyncTask` is doing the job of moving some of the files and then calling `onMigrateSuccess` in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze logcat, check if maybe your activity is destroyed - but I am not sure if android is actually doing this in sleep mode.

One solution would be to aquire PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK for the duration of your AsyncTask, and release it once onPostExecute finishes.

For longer running processes like copying files, consider using [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).